# Snackbar action getView()

Tags: java, android, snackbar

in my Activity I have implement OnClickListener interface

`MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener`

init snackbar like this:

```
snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, R.string.msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.setAction(R.string.action_undo, this);
```

but I cannot handle it on implemented OnClickListener interface method

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // this not work!
    // snackbar id is different from snackbar action id
    if (v.getId() == snackbar.getView().getId()) {

    }
}
```

Someone know how to get action view from snackbar?

Comment: Can you please tell me the exact need for this ?

Comment: The exact need of this is beautiful code structure. A lot of clickable views are handled by one method, method have View v as input parameter and by get ID of this view I can separate my click logic. But snackbar missing action.getView()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For every `Snackbar`, the `Snackbar` textview resource id  is

```
    android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text
```

And the `Snackbar` action view resource id is

```
    android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_action
```

If I correctly understood your question, you want to get the `Snackbar` action resource id. you can easily get that as I mentioned above and in `onClick()` , you can use it like -

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_action) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
v.getId()
```

is always (Reserved) :

```
android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_action
```

[Doc](https://materialdoc.com/components/snackbars-and-toasts/#with-code/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to set action on a snackbar.

```
View.OnClickListener snackbarClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

         }
     };

snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, R.string.msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.setAction(R.string.action_undo, snackbarClickListener);
```

Comment: My question is not about how to add action to snack, I need to know how to get this: snack.getAction().getView()

Comment: As per documentation[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html] Snackbar class does not have `getAction` method. Can you explain something more.